# Bats cannot operate on an array variable exported from the function under test

Tags: arrays, bash, bats-core

Bats is great for testing bash scripts, but its documentation is severely lacking in many areas<sup>1</sup>, including examples and explanations.

I am trying to write a test for a function I've written. However, because the result of this function is a global array, it seems Bats is unable to see it. (This problem may also exist for normal variables, but I could export their contents via `stdout`.)

```bash
#!bats/bin/bats

load 'test_helper/bats-support/load'
load 'test_helper/bats-assert/load'

_load_filetoarray() {
  # Imagine the source of array data is an external file
  declare -a CREATEDARRAY
  CREATEDARRAY=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
  export CREATEDARRAY
}

@test "stackoverflow plain" {
  # Run function that is tested.
  run _load_filetoarray

  # Ensure correct number of lines got loaded
  assert [ "${#CREATEDARRAY[@]}" -eq 3 ]
}
```

The above file, which provides both the function definition (`_load_filetoarray`) and the test, produces the below output on Bats v1.10.0.

```plaintext
stackoverflow.bats
 ✗ stackoverflow plain
   (from function `assert' in file test_helper/bats-assert/src/assert.bash, line 40,
    in test file stackoverflow.bats, line 18)
     `assert [ "${#CREATEDARRAY[@]}" -eq 3 ]' failed
   
   -- assertion failed --
   expression : [ 0 -eq 3 ]
   --
   

1 test, 1 failure
```

If I declare the same function in a separate bash script and run it myself, it works just fine and the array is obviously loaded. But Bats doesn't seem to be able to see the array.

**How can I get Bats to see the array so I can write the unit test to verify that I've written the function correctly?**

**1** Rant about Bats documentation

I'm sorry, it's a great tool, but the documentation is giving me flashbacks to the Bad Old Days of computing, when knowledge was gatekept by Greybeards. It took me YEARS to discover that Bats allowed direct testing of functions, and I only found that out by seeing someone else's test file. I had to back my way into one test that required `run bash -c '...'` with `export -f funcname`. Which came first, `$lines` or `$output`, because one must be derived from the other and that derivation could lead to problems so I'd like to know. Oh, and the official readthedocs.io tutorial goes incoherent in the middle and starts referencing files that weren't previously introduced.

Comment: Arrays can't be exported in a way that exposes anything but only the first element. Array elements are NUL-delimited, and environment variables can't store NULs -- one can conceive of an extension that encodes positioning in the name, creating a separate environment for `varName[0]`, `varName[1]`, etc (presumably with a nonprintable sigil similar to that used for exported functions), but I don't know of any shells that have actually built such a thing.

Comment: Now what you _could_ do is use `declare -p CREATEDARRAY` (aside: don't use all-caps names for your own variables, [they're used for names meaningful to the shell and operating system](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)) to generate a string that recreates your array when `eval`'d, export _that_ and have your child process `eval` it.

Comment: this can be as simple as `run bash -c "$(declare -p arrayname);"'...code that uses "${arrayname[@]}"...'` -- no `export` needed. (You can do the same thing to avoid needing to export functions too, for that matter).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Arrays are absolutely able to be exported, I do it in the main script. I even pass around the array name to make my functions super-reusable. And please don't add Bad Old Days info like that capitalization link to my question--Posix has been dead for 10 years. The "but posix!" and "but Bourne shell!" comments on StackExchange add nothing to the discussion when the topic is modern computing. They just create cruft that readers like me have to wade through when looking for real answers.

Comment: run `testArray=( testOne testTwo testThree ); export testArray; tr '\0' '\n' </proc/self/environ | grep test` -- you'll see that neither `testArray` nor any of the individual elements it contains actually made it into the environment at all.

Comment: ...as an alternate mechanism that's less Linux-specific (doesn't depend on procfs), try it as `testArray=( testOne testTwo testThree ); export testArray; myFunc() { declare -p testArray; }; export -f myFunc; bash -c myFunc` -- you'll see again that the array was not in fact exported. When shushing someone for being pedantic, _do_ be sure you've got your facts straight. (The results described above were generated with bash 5.2.15(1)-release on NixOS 23.05).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My facts are straight, but it seems you have not read what I've typed. As I said, I've been doing what you say is impossible in my script. If you cannot figure out how I can `export` an array and then use all 62 elements of it in the main script and other functions, then maybe you can't provide the help I'm seeking, and that's okay.

Comment: I don't see anything in your script that proves that the `export` is actually required for correct function. Indeed, as you can see from the samples above (which as far as I can tell you've made no effort to explain or refute) _it has no effect_, so it couldn't possibly be required; if it were, your code wouldn't work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I haven't run your code samples because it makes no sense to. If you're actively running, and a doctor tells you that you can't run and they'll prove it if you do XYZ, are you going to try doing XYZ? Or are you going to believe your own feet and ignore them, no matter their expertise?

Comment: You might learn something if you do run them. My best guess is that you're misunderstanding "export" as being equivalent in behavior to `declare -g`, and are under the misapprehension that it's necessary to make a variable set in a function be available outside that function. Insofar as the actual meaning of `export` is about making content _capable of surviving an `execv()` boundary_, and bash's arrays don't do that (as I provided two demonstrations of above)... well, there's clearly _some_ misunderstanding. (Note, an execv, not a fork; no export needed for subshell accessibility)

Comment: (I suppose it's possible there could be a BATS feature that looks for arrays with the `x` flag set, exports a variable with them transformed into `eval`able code, and then evals that code in a child process; but that would be a BATS feature, not baseline shell behavior).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That second sentence is *NOTHING* like what you've said before. It is kind, helps me meet my implied goal, stands alone without long code examples, doesn't quote dead standards, and doesn't tell me that I'm not doing what I know I'm doing. It's still not directly relevant to the Bats situation, but it's great info. Thanks!

Comment: The "long" code samples wouldn't have been necessary if you'd taken me at my word rather than claiming I was telling you untrue things (thus necessitating demonstrations); and I don't think it's reasonable to call POSIX dead as long as bash constrains its development to remain (almost) within the letter of that standard (yes, bash provides additional functionality POSIX doesn't specify, but it does so while avoiding doing things that would constitute violations). While bash continues to follow POSIX, understanding POSIX remains relevant and helpful to understanding bash.

Comment: (...and to speak _specifically_ to the context in which I quoted the standard: while POSIX declares that no conforming shell will give special meaning to variables in namespace X, as long as bash continues to conform with that standard, then bash is guaranteed not to do surprising/unexpected things based on the value of variables in namespace X; thus, for purposes of bash -- as opposed to, say, zsh, which explicitly has decided not to retain compliance -- the standard is very much alive).

Answer (score 0):

Global arrays or other global variables are better avoided. Pass the output array to your function by “reference” (*nameref*) instead.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

f() {
  local -n a1="$1" a2="$2" output="$3"
  local idx
  for idx in "${!a1[@]}" "${!a2[@]}"; do ((output[idx] = 0)) || :; done
  for idx in "${!a1[@]}"; do ((output[idx] += idx * a1[idx])) || :; done
  for idx in "${!a2[@]}"; do ((output[idx] += idx + a2[idx])) || :; done
}

input_one=([0]=3 [1]=5 [2]=7 [11]=11)
input_two=([7]=2 [5]=1 [3]=0 [11]=11)
result=()

f input_{one,two} result

echo "${result[@]@A}"
```

The output:

```bash
declare -a result=([0]="0" [1]="5" [2]="14" [3]="3" [5]="6" [7]="9" [11]="143")
```

Stating the obvious, one can now reference `f` from a `bats` test and have it modify variables:

```bash
@test "stackoverflow plain" {
  local input_one=([0]=3 [1]=5 [2]=7 [11]=11)
  local input_two=([7]=2 [5]=1 [3]=0 [11]=11)
  local result=()

  assert [ -z "${result[*]}" ]
  assert [ -z "${!result[*]}" ]

  f input_{one,two} result

  assert [ "${result[*]}" = '0 5 14 3 6 9 143' ]
  assert [ "${!result[*]}" = '0 1 2 3 5 7 11' ]
}
```

Comment: `set -e` [is an antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Examples); it makes code's behavior version-dependent, context-dependent, [_highly_ nonportable](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) (and -- as supported by that same reference -- subject to a list of rules too long for humans to be reasonably expected to remember), and thus basically impossible to desk-check. Explicit error handling isn't fun to write or review for, but it's the Right Thing.

Comment: Matter of opinion. `set -e` is a _necessity_ in all scripts I ever write, not an antipattern. Behavior of `set -e` is well documented in `man bash` and beneficial for debugging. Scripts without `set -e` will silently obscure errors. Explicit error handling depends on human factor way too strongly. I refuse to depend (solely) on my own discipline (which is virtually nonexistent).

Comment: And scripts _with_ `set -e` silently obscure errors, _but they do it in subtler ways_ -- like deciding to silence an error when someone runs `if yourFunction; then` but not when `yourFunction` is run on its own. (Or, worse, `if thingThatCallsYourFunction; then` -- so you need to know the entire call stack to know if `set -e` will have any effect). That means it's impossible to predict whether `set -e` will work unless you know not just in your script's current state _but after all the ways it's ever modified in the future_ whether it will be called in a "checked" context.

Comment: If you don't have the discipline to write correct shell scripts, perhaps it would be better to use a language that's able to enforce error handling properly instead of reusing the same channel for non-erroneous return value communication and errors (which is really the design decision at the heart of it being impossible to build a suited-to-purpose `set -e` equivalent for any POSIX-family shell).

Comment: In addition to the discipline, I would also need infallibility, which I also lack. `set -e` is by no means perfect (quite the opposite; e.g. `echo "$(echo x; exit 1)"` “succeeds”, despite `set -e`, whereas `a="$(echo x; exit 1)"` fails), but within the constraints of shell scripting (which I may _have to_ do, as I don’t always get to pick the software ecosystem), _something_ (e.g. `set -e`) is better than _nothing_ (e.g. silent failures of random commands in the middle of a script). In terms of productivity, at least in my case, `set -e` wins over manual error handling (attempts), any time.

Comment: Your answer does not address Bats tests at all, so it is useless to me. This is what I'm already doing in the real code itself. FYI, do you realize that this uses global variables? The VALUES of `input_{one,two}` and `result` are not being passed into `f`, REFERENCES to those arrays are what is passed in and you're accessing them directly from the function.

Comment: @Cliff Nothing prevents you from moving the “global” variables into a function or a `bats` test case. My example does work with `bats`, as you would have found out if you had bothered trying it. I’ve added a `bats` snippet to the answer. In any case, a variable reference provided by the caller is arguably a better approach to output arguments (in Bash) than fixed variable names. Fixed variable names may clash. Namerefs prevent (most) name clashes, because they work nicely with `local` variables while avoiding global scope clutter and giving the caller more control over its variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

After even more research and reading, I've found the answer.

Generally, the way to handle testing an array from a function in Bats is to run a subshell and explicitly echo out the array information I want to test.

I have provided specific examples for array length (`echo "${#array[@]}"`), an array "dump" (`echo "${array[@]}"`), and the array line-by-line (`for` loop with `echo $item`).

To ensure that the real function exit status is available to Bats, I need to capture it and `exit` with it, thus the `$err` code.

```bash
#!/bats/bin/bats

load 'test_helper/bats-support/load'
load 'test_helper/bats-assert/load'

_load_filetoarray() {
  # Imagine the source of array data is an external file
  declare -ag CREATEDARRAY
  CREATEDARRAY=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
}

@test "stackoverflow array length" {
  # Run function that is tested.
  export -f _load_filetoarray
  run bash -c '_load_filetoarray ; err=$? ; echo "${#CREATEDARRAY[@]}" ; exit $err'

  # Ensure correct number of lines got loaded
  assert_equal "${output}" 3
  assert_not_equal "${output}" 2
}

@test "stackoverflow array dump" {
  # Run function that is tested.
  export -f _load_filetoarray
  run bash -c '_load_filetoarray ; err=$? ; echo "${CREATEDARRAY[@]}" ; exit $err'

  # Ensure output is correct
  assert_output 'aaa bbb ccc'
  refute_output 'aaa'
}

@test "stackoverflow array lines" {
  # Run function that is tested.
  export -f _load_filetoarray
  run bash -c '_load_filetoarray ; err=$? ; for i in "${CREATEDARRAY[@]}"; do echo "${i}"; done ; exit $err'

  # Ensure output lines are correct
  assert_line --index 0 'aaa'
  assert_line --index 1 'bbb'
  assert_line --index 2 'ccc'
  refute_line 'ddd'
}
```

The tests all pass.

```plaintext
stackoverflow.bats
 ✓ stackoverflow array length
 ✓ stackoverflow array dump
 ✓ stackoverflow array lines

3 tests, 0 failures
```

I can confirm that this method works on my real code. For posterity, this is an excerpt of how that was done.

```bash
setup_file() {
  # Set variable for test file filename
  testfile="_resources/testfile.log"
  # export required in this case
  export testfile
  # Set variable for testfile length
  testfilelen=$(wc --lines "${testfile}" | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1)
  # export required in this case
  export testfilelen
}

@test "loadfiletoarray length" {
  # Load the script that has the function to be tested.
  source ../scriptundertest.sh

  # Run function that is tested.
  export -f _load_filetoarray    # export required in this case
  run bash -c '_load_filetoarray "${testfile}" ; err=$? ; echo "${#CREATEDARRAY[@]}" ; exit $err'

  # Verify result is as expected.
  assert_success  # Ensure no problem loading the file in with `mapfile`

  # These are equivalent in this case
  assert_output "${testfilelen}"
  assert_equal "${output}" "${testfilelen}"

  # If _load_filetoarray outputs something of its own on stdout,
  # I would need to `assert_line --index -1` to test the last output line.
}
```

(Thanks to @CharlesDuffy, I realized that `declare -g` was the way to get the array truly global, not `export`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to export it from the function. Here is a modified version of your script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bats

load 'test_helper/bats-support/load'
load 'test_helper/bats-assert/load'

_load_filetoarray() {
   declare -ag CREATEDARRAY=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc")
}

@test "stackoverflow plain" {
   # Execute the tested function.
   run _load_filetoarray

   # Make sure the number of rows loaded is correct
   assert [ "${#CREATEDARRAY[@]}" -eq 3 ]
}
```

Changes made:

1. Removed the export statement from the array declaration.
2. Use `declare -ag` to declare and export the array in one step.

This should solve the problem of Bats not recognizing arrays. Make sure to replace the `#!/usr/bin/env bats` line with the correct path to your Bats interpreter.

Comment: As written, this code fails the `assert` on my system because `${#CREATEDARRAY[@]}=0`. I'm running  bash `5.2.15(1)-release` and Bats `1.10.0`. What versions of bash and Bats did you run your code under, that it worked?